# what function in react web is similar to InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions() in native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was using a community component that did not dynamically change a url, so I saw this solution in native but in react web there is a function similar to this?

ex:

InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
setLoading(false)
}

Answer (score -1):

I think, that using listeners to window will help (like window.requestAnimationFrame).

Comment: Please provide code demonstrating how this proposed solution solves the question. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell if this is even a valid answer to the provided question. Adding an example is a good way to demonstrate that this does actually accomplish what the OP is asking for, and it makes it a lot easier for future readers to determine if this is the solution to their problem.